# Single quote escaping in Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to query users by displayName, but I have trouble escaping single quote when sending the request by both C# SDK and Graph Explorer.

Update: It's not clear in the example, the search term I have trouble with is `I'`

Example query: 
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=startsWith(displayName,'I%27') results in

```
Status Code: 400
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "There is an unterminated string literal at position 28 in 'startsWith(displayName,'I'')'.",
        // snip
    }
}
```

I tried all sorts of escaping, with backslashes, double quotes, `%2527` instead of the quote, nothing works. What's the proper way to query with a quote?

Comment: We won't be able to run your example since we lack the access token. But try mixing quotes instead of escaping: `filter=startsWith(displayName,"I'")`

Comment: I don't think this works: Syntax error: character '\"' is not valid at position 23 in 'startsWith(displayName,\"I'\")'.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=startsWith(displayName,'I''')
```

Based on http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/abnf/odata-abnf-construction-rules.txt:

> SQUOTE-in-string = SQUOTE SQUOTE ; two consecutive single quotes
>   represent one within a string literal

Comment: How to escape "&"?

Comment: Yes, i am also facing issue with & .  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60603198/issue-in-matching-department-name-while-using-microsoft-graph-api-v1-0