# Microsoft Graph filter groups with # in name

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I`m working on app using Microsoft Graph to manage groups in AAD.
When trying to filter groups that name contains #, using following query:

```
groups?$filter=(startswith(displayName,'#'))
```

Exact filter clause of code in C# that produces this error is following:

```
Filter($"(startswith(displayName,'{name}') or startswith(mail,'{name}'))")
```

I get following response from Graph:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Invalid filter clause",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "4d80e6a8-326a-4f79-9ea4-0e7924954181",
            "date": "2018-02-06T09:56:01"
        }
    }
}
```

Documentation does not mention that # is invalid character, moreover- groups are created properly with this character in name.

Can someone confirm that this is a bug in Graph?

I noticed that manual encoding `#` as `%23` seems to fix the issue and filtering works fine.

**EDIT** - interesting thing - apostrophe `'` throws this error even if it`s encoded as `%27`.

Comment: # is a special character in URLs (bookmark anchor). So you should definitely URL encode it - as you have already discovered. Same goes for non-ASCII characters in the property values.

Comment: @RasmusW this would be obvious for using special characters in web-world. Graph SDK should handle encoding of URL`s at its own.

Comment: Tomasz, I appreciate your feedback regarding query option encoding. We'll add this to our backlog.

Comment: @DmitryPimenov thank you for feedback. Do you possibly have any tips on how to hack this to work with apostrophe search?

Comment: You were correct to encode the `#`. Unfortunately, I'm not sure if there is a work around for the apostrophe.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41516526/5199691 for how to handle apostrophe