# Issue in Matching Department Name while using Microsoft Graph API V1.0

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, escaping, microsoft-graph-api

I am using below code to match Department Name:

```
string departmentName = "Admin";

var departmentPeoples = await graphServiceClient.Users.Request().Filter($"department eq '{departmentName}'").Select(u => new {
    u.DisplayName,
    u.MobilePhone,
    u.BusinessPhones,
    u.UserPrincipalName
}).GetAsync();
```

This works, but when my  search string is `Admin & IT` ,it doesn't work because of & sign.
I tried using `var departmentname ="Admin \& IT"`
But still it shows error:

> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Code: BadRequest Message: Invalid filter clause or string doesn't match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to convert "&" to "%26" manually.

You could use `var departmentname ="Admin %26 IT"` in this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot ,it works . But for characters like ( ,) and - when i apply same logic ,it doesn't work. ( -> %28 , ) ->  %29 , - ->  %2D and so on.

Comment: @AllTech It seems that not all the characters need to be converted. I had a quick test about ",". Using `var departmentname ="Admin , IT"` is enough.